# Vuejs how to output the date of entire week (format example: May 4 - 10 2020) and weekday (Monday......Sunday) vue-moment

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

Currently I am trying to output a date and weekday in letters. The first following picture below is what it outputs now with the v-for loop.

[image]

```js
 <div v-for="(country, index) in info" :key="index"> 
  <template v-if="index == 0">
     {{ country.datetime }}
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    {{ country.datetime ||  moment("dddd") }}
  </template>
  {{ Math.floor((country.min_temp + country.max_temp) / 2) }}
</div>
```

What I actually trying to achieve is the following output with the right date format. The first temperature is the average of Monday till Sunday. But want to achieve the date format like

> May 4 - 10 2020 (entire week)

Then below it should only output the weekday itself (Monday - Sunday). How should I fix that. If you know a better solution, then do not hesitate to share it in here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created two different methods, the one that already has been shown above, but outputting the full week days check below.

```js
 <div v-for="(country, index) in info" :key="index"> 
  <template v-if="index == 0">
     {{ weekDate(country.datetime) }}
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    {{ dayFullName(country.datetime) }}
  </template>
  {{ Math.floor((country.min_temp + country.max_temp) / 2) }}
</div>    
    
methods: {
  weekDate (value) {
    const entireWeek = moment(value).format("MMMM D -") + moment(value).add(7, 'days').format("D YYYY") 
    return entireWeek; // July 6 - 13 2020
  },
  dayFullName (date) {
    const getFullName = moment(date).format('dddd');
    return getFullName // Monday, Tuesday etcetera
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just take the first 7 days (and make sure u start with Monday) to calculate the average temperature and use the following to formate it

```
const date = moment();
var FormatedDate = date.format('MMM D - ') + date.add(7, 'days').format('D YYYY');
console.log(FormatedDate);
```

for the days u don't need any format actually, pure HTML would be enough since the first element from the array is Monday and has the temperature for the day too. Hope i could understand your quastion